# OCR (Optical character Recognition)

Tags: ocr, captcha, barcode, qr-code

I just got a doubt it's not clear with the search engine results. 
Can OCR (Optical character Recognition) read captcha, QR-code and barcodes?

1. Captcha.
2. QR-code.
3. Barcodes.
4. Licence codes

Comment: OCR's purpose is to recognize characters (as the name says). To detect barcodes (1D or 2D) you should use software to image recognition, which is similar, but certainly not only OCR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends on captcha. Standard OCR isn't meant for CAPTCHA breaking. Anyway simple captcha can be preprocessed and then fed to an OCR engine, sometimes it works... In general CAPTCHA breaking is much more complex than downloading the Tesseract binaries. If it were that easy, all of the paid services would be out of business overnight.
2. QR Codes and barcodes are both optical machine-readable data systems capable of conveying large amounts of data. Both are extremely useful in their own right. They have important differences but not regarding your question... so see point 3
3. The error correction capabilities of bar code recognition engines are way beyond that of OCR engines. A damaged bar code can easily be read. Also, most barcodes either work or they don't. OCR can confidently misread letters, while barcodes are "fail-safe".